# Xcode project navigator background color

Tags: xcode7

When a window is active in xcode project navigator background color blue, and when two or more it is default. How to make that it was always defaulted?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGtaJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was on the system side. The wallpapers color mixed with color of IDE. I reduced transparency. So that was it.

Comment: where did you reduced the transparency?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to change colors in Xcode.

First is the "Fonts & Colors" tab in Xcode's preferences, which look like this:
[image: Fonts and Colors]
That doesn't change the color of the files in the Project Navigator, though. To do that, in System Preferences there's a tab helpfully named "General", you can change the settings for your system in it.  Here's what it looks like for me now:
[image: General System Preferences]

I chose "Graphite", and that changes selected files in the Project Navigator to have gray surrounding the filenames.
[image: Two Files Selected]

Comment: I meant the color of the navigator background. On your screenshot color is gray. I also want to gray, but I have for some reason blue.  http://imgur.com/mxHC0ta

Comment: You can do that by changing the appearance in the "General" System Preference to "Graphite".

Comment: When I change the Appearance, the only change the highlight color of the selected file . I want to change the color of the all background.   http://imgur.com/SEdFK6n

Comment: I thought I was covering all the bases in my "really long explanation" @MikeBedar ; do you have suggestions as to how I could improve my answer?